# Python substitute regex by variable contains special carachter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to substitute using re:

```
buffer = 'my_path: any_suffix'
share_path = '\\\\server\\final'
buffer = re.sub('my_path:.*', fr'my_path: {share_path}', buffer)
```

In the buffer I get:

```
'my_path: \\server\x0cinal'
```

instead of resired:

```
'my_path: \\server\final'
```

If I use
`share_path = '\\\\server\\Final'` (with capital 'F') - it works OK.

What can be done?

Comment: Is there any special requirement to use an f-string literal, or can you use a regular string literal with `str.format`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The only requirements to use variable (share_path) and perform substitution.

Comment: So does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658435/3832970) solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to double escape the backslash in the replacement pattern **and** it seems the best way to use the variable in this case is to use `str.format` here rather than the f-string literal (`fr'my_path: {share_path.replace("\\", "\\\\")}'` will throw *`SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`*):

```py
buffer = re.sub('my_path:.*', r'my_path: {}'.format(share_path.replace("\\", "\\\\")), buffer)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/guwhgH).

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
buffer.replace('any_suffix', re.sub(r"\\s+", "s", share_path))
```